# How to play .rm files in android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

MediaPlayer plays .mp3 files without any problem. But while playing .rm files it through exception.

Code:

```
try{
     AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("song.rm");
     MediaPlayer player;
     player = new MediaPlayer();
     player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
     player.prepare();
     player.start();                
  } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception while Playing: "+e);                  
    }
```

Exception :

```
01-30 16:42:11.126: E/MediaPlayer(1404): Unable to to create media player
01-30 16:42:11.126: I/System.out(1404): Exception while Playing : java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
```

Answer (score 2):

RealMedia (`.rm`) is not one of Android's [supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

Comment: Thanks sharing the link. Is there any API to convert .rm to mp3 and then play using media player.

Comment: @user1664942: Android itself has no such API, as RealMedia is not one of Android's supported media formats. Most likely, there is third-party code that can do this (e.g., `ffmpeg`), but I have no personal experience in trying to use such code on Android.

Comment: Thanks bro. Let me try with third party API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create it.

```
public static MediaPlayer create (Context context, int resid)
```

Comment: Will try this & with third party APIs